# SDcard not showing full size in gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, sd-card

So I was trying to put an embedded linux image inside an SDcard (32gb) and used the famous 'dd' command... Apparently it failed because now I cant format the disk anymore, in my Disks utility i get quarq error messages if I try to do something with the partitions in the SDcard (image 1).
[image: NORMAL DISK UTILITY WINDOW]

I installed GPARTED, but in there I can't even see the partitions and can only see 64kib of memory space (image2).
[image: GPARTED WINDOW]

I even tried to execute some command I've seen in other forums, but didn't work. Command I tried:

```
wipefs -a /dev/your-device
```

I tried this one that was a solution to another question made here, but also didn't solve the problem:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=2048 count=32
```

Comment: Be aware that you are getting into pretty dangerous stuff here. You made a small typo that rendered your SD card unusable until fixed. If you made a different small typo, you would have done it to your computer's hard drive / SSD, instead, and rendered your computer unusable. Be very cautious when running commands you don't totally understand.

Answer (score 4):

You have overwritten the partition table on your SD card because you forgot the "1" at the end of `/dev/sdd1`. Let's recreate the partition table:

**Warning: Make sure you select the right device!** Since you want "to put an embedded linux image inside an SDcard", I assume you don't care if the previous data is lost. You have been conflating sda and sdd in your question.

## Gparted option

1. Go to Device > Create partition table

[image: device menu]

2. Ensure "msdos" is selected, and click "Apply"

[image: partition table dialog]

3. Follow any remaining prompts

## Gnome-disks option

1. Click on the three dots and click "Format Disk..."

[image: overflow menu]

2. Ensure the second dropdown is set to "MBR / DOS", and click "Format..."

[image: format disk dialog]

3. Follow any remaining prompts

## Command line option

```bash
echo 2048 | sudo sfdisk --label dos /dev/sdd
partprobe
# Now /dev/sdd1 should exist for dd
```

## Writing the disk image

- Option 1: I highly recommend you use the "Restore Disk Image..." feature of gnome-disks
- Option 2: Don't forget the number at the end of `/dev/sdd1` when you use `dd` this time

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=2048 count=32` didn't work because that just destroys the partition table again. The tools are confused because the partition table is missing, so the fix is to recreate the partition table.

Comment: When trying to do the 'GNOME-DISK OPTION' i got the error message saying "Error syncronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Comment: In the 'GParted OPTION' nothing happens and I only have sda as only device and not sda1 or sda2, so I only have access to that sda with 64Kib

Comment: I added a command line option. In gparted, you are supposed to see sda without the number in the dropdown and sda1 in the table. Make sure there are other disks other than sda so you don't overwrite your current OS.

Comment: I tried that command line option you added but got this result 
`Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK

Disk /dev/sda: 553 KiB, 566272 bytes, 1106 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

>>> Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xb0cbe204.
/dev/sda1: Start sector 2048 out of range.
Failed to add #1 partition: Resultado numérico fora do intervalo
Leaving.
`

Comment: That means /dev/sda (no 1) was detected by the kernel to be too small to have the location 2048. You could try running `partprobe` before it. Otherwise, I don't know of any way to change the kernel's view of `/sys/class/block/sda/size` (it's not writable). Your SD card could have been used too much and now there are too many bad blocks and there is not much capacity left